# Getting NullPointerException, but cant find the source

Tags: java, exception, mapreduce

I have this piece of MapReduce code. It says i have a NullPointerException in my `cleanup()`, but i can seem to figure out where it is. I even added a while loop to avoid null values, but that doesn't seem to work. This is a MapReduce job, but the fundamentals remain the same. I'd describe my data, but i am not sure it is relevant to the question.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class xvaluesMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> 
{
public Map<String, Long> snpLocations = new LinkedHashMap<String, Long>();
public Map<Long, String> nList = new LinkedHashMap<Long, String>(); 
public ArrayList<Long> l = new ArrayList<Long>();

public void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
{
    super.setup(context);
    URI [] SNPLocation =context.getCacheFiles();

    if(SNPLocation.length == 0)
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Distributed Cache file not found.");

    File localFile = new File(SNPLocation[0]);
    FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(localFile);


    int lineStream;
    while((lineStream = f.read()) != -1)
    {
        String strLine = String.valueOf(lineStream);// line;
        String[] tokens = strLine.toString().split("\\t");
        String SNPID =  tokens[1];
        long location = Long.parseLong(tokens[3]);

        snpLocations.put(SNPID, location);  
    }

    f.close();

    l.addAll(snpLocations.values());




}

public void map(LongWritable key, Text values, Context context)
{
    String [] value = values.toString().split("\\s");
    long position=0;

    for(String s: value)
    {
        ++position;
        nList.put(position, s);
    }
}

public void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{

    while(l != null){
    for (long nPosition: l)

        {
        long actualPos = nPosition+7;
        long secActualPos = actualPos+1;
        //I used 7 because I am assuming the count for the nucleotide position starts from one instead of zero. Also There are 6 other variables like familyID, individual ID....etc
        //in the data set. The "secActualPos" is to account for the second pair.

        String twoSNPphenoTindID = nList.get(actualPos).toString() + "," + nList.get(secActualPos).toString()+  "," + nList.get(5).toString() + "," + nList.get(1);

        for(Entry<String, Long> entryPos: snpLocations.entrySet())
        {
            if(entryPos.getValue().equals(nPosition))


            context.write(new Text(String.valueOf(actualPos)), new Text(twoSNPphenoTindID));
        }
    }

};
```

}}

Comment: If you've done even the slightest search on this site regarding NullPointerException, you'd see that we need to see the actual stack trace and know exactly what line is throwing the exception. Well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`l` is a `ArrayList<Long>`. Meaning that it can hold objects with null value. When you do this `for (long nPosition: l)`, you are iterating over all elements, but also it is calling the method `longValue()` of the `Long` objects within the ArrayList. If there is an object with a `null` value, you will have a `NullPointerException`. It is the same as this.

```
Long element = null;
long a = element;
```

This throws a `NullPointerException` because when you try to asign Long to a primitive long, it is realy trying to do this

```
long a = element.longValue()
```

And because element is null, you cannot reference a method of a null object.

Use `for (Long nPosition: l)` instead of `for (long nPosition: l)`, then check `nPosition` for `null` value inside the loop like this

```
for (Long nPosition: l)
    {
    if(nPosition == null)
        continue;

    long actualPos = nPosition+7;
    long secActualPos = actualPos+1;
    //I used 7 because I am assuming the count for the nucleotide position starts from one instead of zero. Also There are 6 other variables like familyID, individual ID....etc
    //in the data set. The "secActualPos" is to account for the second pair.

    String twoSNPphenoTindID = nList.get(actualPos).toString() + "," + nList.get(secActualPos).toString()+  "," + nList.get(5).toString() + "," + nList.get(1);

    for(Entry<String, Long> entryPos: snpLocations.entrySet())
    {
        if(entryPos.getValue().equals(nPosition))


        context.write(new Text(String.valueOf(actualPos)), new Text(twoSNPphenoTindID));
    }
```